# R: source multiple files with chdir = TRUE using safely

Tags: r

I want to run multiple R scripts that are located in different sub-folders in the "path_source".

```
files <- list.files(path = path_source, full.names = T, recursive = T)
```

Scripts that don't run correctly should not stop the program, therefore I use safely()

```
safesource <- safely(source)
map_chr(files, safesource)
```

However, in the source() function, I need to pass the additional argument "chdir = T" to change directories accordingly. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below does what exactly what I wanted.

```
files <- list.files(path = pathsource, full.names = T, recursive = T)
sourcefile <- function(file) {
  source(file, chdir = T)
}
safesource <- safely(sourcefile)
sourceinfo <- map(files, safesource)
```

I consider this solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `safesource`

```
safesource <- function(file) purrr::safely(source(file, chdir = TRUE))
```

Comment: ```safesource <- safely(source)
map(files, safesource)``` seems to return a list with information about the files that have been sourced. That's what I need. I can't seem to get this information with the safesource as a wrapped function as you propose.

Comment: @jwr That is what you have tried but it not how I defined `safesource`. Please check my answer.